How to copy files and folders in HDFS using Pyspark
I have folder structure like this on HDFS
/user/test/data/data_backlog
Inside data_backlog, I have date folders like below
   dt=2023.01.01
        part1.avro
        part2.avro
   dt=2023.01.02
        part1.avro
        part2.avro

I need to copy the files by maintaining the same folder structure to another path
/user/test/data/data_backlog_backup
This is my present code:
# get directory list to be moved
directories = get_list_path(end_date, lake.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path('/user/test/data/data_backlog')),False)

for _par in directories:
    df_bkp = spark.read.format('avro').load(_par)
    DataIO.write(df_bkp.coalesce(5), "data_backlog", "overwrite")
    lake.Delete(fs.Path(_par), True)

This is doing the job, but its moving all the files into parent folder without creating date sub-folders.
How to maintain the same folder structure in the destination path

If I understand well, this code will do the job simply and quickly by using the partitionBy option :
df = spark.read.format('avro').load("/user/test/data/data_backlog")
df.write.partitionBy("dt").format('avro').save("/user/test/data/data_backlog_backup")

